# Alphanumeric JavaScript RegEx for Password Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regex below to validate password to accept alphanumeric characters only. The regex works if I enter 2 characters one alpha and one number but if more than two characters my regex doesn't work. I want if possible the following results as shown in "Expected Behavior". Can anyone help me rewrite my regex?

**JavaScript**

```
  function checkPasswordComplexity(pwd) {
        var regularExpression = /^[a-zA-Z][0-9]$/;
        var valid = regularExpression.test(pwd);
        return valid;
    }
```

**Current Behavior**

```
Password:Valid
a1:true
aa1:false
aa11:false
```

**Expected Behavior**

```
Password:Valid
aa:false (should have at least 1 number) 
1111111:false (should have at least 1 letter)
aa1:true
aa11:true
a1a1a1a1111:true
```

Comment: Use match() instead of test()

Comment: Don't limit characters allowed in password, it only makes them weaker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to add "one or more", you're currently checking for a letter followed by a number.

Try:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

`+` means 'one or more'

I also joined the ranges.

Note: I don't understand why you'd want to limit the password to such a small range though,  having a wide character range will make your passwords *stronger*.

#### [Here is a fiddle demonstrating the correct behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/fsEv8/)

If you just want to validate that the password has at least one letter and at least one number, you can check like this:

```
function checkPasswordComplexity(pwd) {
    var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/; 
    var number = /[0-9]/;
    var valid = number.test(pwd) && letter.test(pwd); //match a letter _and_ a number
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: From my understanding, the OP wants the string to have at least one letter AND at least one number.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum thanks for this! It solved my issue. Well with regards to the simplest password complexity it's the needs our our client to have an aphanumeric password only. In fact some local banks here still have alphanumeric password only. Even us still wondering why they haven't switch to complex password. Thanks once again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. It is my experience, that when working in teams where not everyone is a regex wiz, it is better to avoid things like look-aheads and look-behinds unless you are sure people understand them. It is a nice and powerful concept, but it makes code that is unreadable for people who only know the basic regular expressions. Good luck!

Comment: If the aim of the solution is to validate inputs that contain BOTH letters and numbers then this does not work.

Answer (score 5):

```
function checkPasswordComplexity(pwd) {
        var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;
        var valid = regularExpression.test(pwd);
        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]{2,}$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
var regularExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

This means "one or more letter or number."

However, some users might also want to enter symbols (like `&*#`) in their passwords. If you just want to make sure there is at least one letter and number while still allowing symbols, try something like this:

```
var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+$/;
```

The `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` is a positive lookahead. This means that it makes sure that there is a letter ahead of it, but it doesn't affect the regex.

Comment: The second one will never match, you want `/^(?=.*[A-Z])` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
var pwd=document.getElementById('pwd').value;
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/;  
var re=reg.test(pwd);
alert(re);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think lookaround aren't supported by javascript, so you can use:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-zA-Z]+)
```

But if they are supported:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{2,}$/
```