# make a regex to validate a string with only one number

Tags: javascript, regex

here my probleme, in some project i need to validate a string, it must be a length of 4 character and contains one and only one number but i don't know it's place (can be "er1t" or "4frt" but not "sdfd" or "4fd5")

i have made a regex which work : `(?:[a-z]\d[a-z]{2}|\d[a-z]{3}|[a-z]{2}\d[a-z]|[a-z]{3}\d)` but it's not optimised and I don't find how i search for a number in a string in regex, i use a javascript regex.

Thank in advance,

ekanS

Comment: Hi, could you please state the language/tool you are using the regex in?

Comment: I have just add it ;)

Comment: Here's a pretty [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16814000/1578604) with a bit more rules than your own. Can you figure it out from that? The accepted answer is using multiple regex, the other upvoted ones use 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use

```
^(?=[a-z]*\d[a-z]*$)[a-z\d]{4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG7xL6/6).

In short, we can set a `(?=\D*\d\D*$)` condition to check if the whole line/string has only 1 number at the very start of a line/string. Then we can allow any lowercase letters and numbers.

If you plan to allow upper case letters, add `A-Z` to the character class, or use `i` option.

```js
function isValid(code) {
   var re = /^(?=[a-z]*\d[a-z]*$)[a-z\d]{4}$/gm; 
   if ((m = re.exec(code)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML + "<br>" + m[0] + " is <font color=\"#0000FF\">valid</font>.";
   }
   else { 
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML + "<br>" + code + " is <font color=\"#FF0000\">not valid</font>.";
    }
}

isValid('er1t');
isValid('4frt'); 
isValid('sdfd');
isValid('4fd5');
isValid('ffd5');

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML + "</font>"
```

```html
<div id="res"><font face="Arial"><b>Valid codes:</b><font face="Tahoma"><div>
```